# separate joined business names,mobile phone, town and email for each instance

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
a = """ ABC Limited, Nairobi0754009522info@kenyagreats.com DEF Limited, Nairobi0737 308 793info@defoptions.co.ke GHI Electrical Services, Mombasa+254787254230info@ghielectricalservices.co.ke JKL Limited, Kakamega+254541112470jkl@yahoo.com MNO Kenya, Nairobi0797429578mnoe@gmail.com"""

re.split('(^[A-Za-z ,]+)([\+ 0-9]+)([a-z@\]', a)
```

Pls, help me to split joined business names,mobile phone, town and email for each instance

Comment: please ignore all 'enter code here'. They are not part of the text. Thank you.

Comment: Please See below:

ABC Limited, Nairobi0754009522info@kenyagreats.com

DEF Limited, Nairobi0737 308 793info@defoptions.co.ke

GHI Electrical Services, Mombasa+254787254230info@ghielectricalservices.co.ke
JKL Limited, Kakamega+254541112470jkl@yahoo.com
MNO Kenya, Nairobi0797429578mnoe@gmail.com

Comment: please click [edit] and improve your question.. see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: This is the code I am using and its giving me an error:

Comment: import re
a = ABC Limited, Nairobi0754009522info@kenyagreats.com
re.split('(^[A-Za-z ,]+)([\+ 0-9]+)([a-z@\]', a)

Answer (score 0):

This seems workable for your case to extract strings separately from your data.

```
(?si)\s*(?P<biz>[ ,a-z]+)(?P<mobile>[\d\s\+]{10,})(?P<email>(?![ ])[@a-z\.]+)
```

[Demo,,,](https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/92) in which captures strings respectively to `group<biz>`, `group<mobile>`, `group<email>`

And python scrips may be like this

```
ss=""" ABC Limited, Nairobi0754009522info@kenyagreats.com DEF Limited, Nairobi0737 308 793info@defoptions.co.ke GHI Electrical Services, Mombasa+254787254230info@ghielectricalservices.co.ke JKL Limited, Kakamega+254541112470jkl@yahoo.com MNO Kenya, Nairobi0797429578mnoe@gmail.com"""

regx=re.compile(r'(?si)\s*(?P<biz>[ ,a-z]+)(?P<mobile>[\d\s\+]{10,})(?P<email>(?![ ])[@a-z\.]+)')
print(regx.sub(r'\g<biz>                    \g<mobile>              \g<email>\n', ss))
```

Output is

```
ABC Limited, Nairobi                    0754009522              info@kenyagreats.com
DEF Limited, Nairobi                    0737 308 793                info@defoptions.co.ke
GHI Electrical Services, Mombasa                    +254787254230               info@ghielectricalservices.co.ke
JKL Limited, Kakamega                   +254541112470               jkl@yahoo.com
MNO Kenya, Nairobi                  0797429578              mnoe@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer was very useful.